# Get the word after a particular word in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How do I get the word after a particular word in a Ruby string?

For example:

```
From:Ysxrb<abc@gmail.com>\nTo: <xyzn@gmail.com>Subject: xyzabc\nDate: Tue, 19 Jun 2012   03:26:56 -0700\nMessage-ID: <9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>
```

I just want to get:

```
Ysxrb<abc@gmail.com

xyzabc
```

Comment: Your final goal seems to be trying to parse emails. Perhaps email_reply_parser would fit your need ? https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question/requirement may need a bit of refinement.

You state:  "How to get the word after a particular word in a ruby string?" and your example text is this :  "From:Ysxrb\nTo: Subject: xyzabc\nDate: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 03:26:56 -0700\nMessage-ID: <9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>"

and then you finally say that what you really want out of these string are the following words:

"'Ysxrb' and  'xyzabc'".

Will you always be parsing email text, which is what this appears to be? If so, then there are some more specific approaches you could take. For instance, in this example you could do something like this:

```
eml = "From:Ysxrb\nTo: Subject: xyzabc\nDate: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 03:26:56 -0700\nMessage-ID: <9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>"
tokens = eml.split(/[\s\:]/)
```

which would yield this:

```
["From", "Ysxrb", "To", "", "Subject", "", "xyzabc", "Date", "", "Tue,", "19", "Jun", "2012",     "03", "26", "56", "-0700", "Message-ID", "", "<9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>"]
```

At this point, if the word following "To" and "Subject" are what you're after, you could simply get the first non-blank array element after each one, like this:

```
tokens[tokens.find_index("From") + 1]  => "Ysxrb"
tokens[tokens.find_index("Subject") + 2]  => "xyzabc"  # + 2 is needed because of the newline.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expresion, try this on a irb console:

```
string = "From:Ysxrb<abc@gmail.com>\nTo: <xyzn@gmail.com>Subject:"
/From:(.+)\n/.match string
$1
```

**$1** hold the backreference we capture with the parenthesis in the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regexp, here's an example:

```
>> s = "From:Ysxrb\nTo: Subject: xyzabc\nDate: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 03:26:56 -0700\nMessage-ID: <9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>"
=> "From:Ysxrb\nTo: Subject: xyzabc\nDate: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 03:26:56 -0700\nMessage-ID: <9D.A1.02635.ABB40EF4@ecout1>"
>> m, w1, w2 = s.match(/^From:(\w*)\W+.*Subject: (\w*)/).to_a
=> ["From:Ysxrb\nTo: Subject: xyzabc", "Ysxrb", "xyzabc"]
>> w1
=> "Ysxrb"
>> w2
=> "xyzabc"
```

to find out a good regexp for your requirements, you may use [rubular, a Ruby regular expression editor](http://rubular.com/r/TWjOnfoSQr)